# Some classes of tailwind suddenly not working in my Preact + Vite application

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, postcss, preact

I used to work with TailwindsV3, Preact, and Vite3, And they work well.

I extended the tailwind theme and it worked just fine.

However, After I tweaked a bit of tailwind config,
Some classes of default tailwind suddenly stop working,
And never able to get it to work again even if I turn the config back.

For example,
Classes with padding 1 and 2 like `p-1` `px-2` are missing.
But classes with padding 3 and 4 like `p-3` `py-4` are still there.

[image]

It didn't turn back even after I removed all of my extended themes.

Does anyone know what's happing here?

---

Here are my configurations

`postcss.config.cjs`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

`tailwind.config.cjs`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "primary": "#242424",
        "gray": {
          "1": "#EAEAEA",
          "2": "#ACB5BD",
          "3": "#838A90",
          "4": "#2B2F35",
        }
      },
      borderWidth: {
        '05': '0.5px',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "editor",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.10.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@preact/preset-vite": "^2.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.0.7"
  }
}
```

---

Here is what I've tried that didn't work.
(After I've removed all of my extended themes)

- Clear `node_modules` and `yarn install` again.
- Run using `vite build` and `vite preview`
- Clear browser caches / Change the browser.

Comment: Probably that `content` part needs modification. Looks like tailwind is not seeing some of your files. Can you post your directory structure? Also, have you added those classes directly in index.html? If so, then you need to add `'./index.html'` to the content array.

Comment: I didn't add it directly in the index.html. I added it via preact component.
But I deleted most of HTML tags in the screenshot to have bare minimum example.

Comment: I think the content part works fine because if I remove it all of the Tailwind classes will be gone.

Comment: It doesn't need to be removed. You need to add some more patterns to it. I can't tell for sure unless you add your directory structure to the post.

Comment: @brc-dd I think you probably right. I did try as a simple tailwind on the `src/app.tsx`. All the classes work fine.

Comment: Let me try myself before I get back with more directory structure info. Thanks so much for bearing with me.

Comment: @brc-dd I think I've found the issue, It's caused by dynamic class names in my code. Thanks for hinting me again.

Comment: Ah, That's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is Tailwind is not supporting dynamic class name construction, I've used it in my code.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names